# This code always give an error of duplicate insertion - How to solve that?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I am trying to create an insertion in some tables with random data but i have a problem with the duplicates.

I wrote an insertion of random records in postgresql b but it returns duplicates detection and there should be no duplicates i am using every name for exactly 2680 times and the names are 22 for 58960 records total of table play_in please check and tell what's wrong with it and how does produce a duplicate.

import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import java.util.Random;

```
public class PostgreSQLJDBC {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Connection c = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        int year;
        int year1;
        int num_rating;
        int num_ratingAvg;
        String[] round = new String[5];
        round[0] = "32nd";
        round[1] = "16th";
        round[2] = "quarter_final";
        round[3] = "SemiFinal";
        round[4] = "FInal";
        String[] name1 = new String[22];
        name1[0] = "ahmed";
        name1[1] = "mohamed";
        name1[2] = "mai";
        name1[3] = "salma";
        name1[4] = "walid";
        name1[5] = "wael";
        name1[6] = "fadwa";
        name1[7] = "nada";
        name1[8] = "nahla";
        name1[9] = "mustafa";
        name1[10] = "ola";
        name1[11] = "omar";
        name1[12] = "amr";
        name1[13] = "beshoy";
        name1[14] = "marina";
        name1[15] = "gerges";
        name1[16] = "botros";
        name1[17] = "mina";
        name1[18] = "menna";
        name1[19] = "feasal";
        name1[20] = "youssef";
        name1[21] = "moussa";
        Random id = new Random();
        Random roundc = new Random();
        String round1;
        int idc;
        String name;
        Random namec = new Random();
        int namecounter = 0;
        Random belle = new Random();
        int belec = 0;
        Random yearc = new Random();
        Random num_ratingsc = new Random();
        int num_ratingSum = 0;
        // roundc.nextInt(4);
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/a2", "mohamed", "1234");
            System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
            String sql3;
            String sql4;
            stmt = c.createStatement();
            String sql = "CREATE TABLE cup_matches "
                    + "(MID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,"
                    + " ROUND           TEXT    NOT NULL, "
                    + " YEAR            INT     NOT NULL, "
                    + " NUM_RATINGS     INT     NOT NULL, "
                    + " RATING          INT     NOT NULL)";
            String sql1 = "CREATE TABLE played_in "
                    + "(MID         INT       NOT NULL,"
                    + " NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL, "
                    + " YEAR            INT     NOT NULL, "
                    + " POSITION     INT     NOT NULL, "
                    + "CONSTRAINT pk_played_in PRIMARY KEY (MID, NAME));";

            String sql2 = "ALTER TABLE played_in ADD CONSTRAINT ref FOREIGN KEY (MID) REFERENCES cup_matches (MID);";

            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql1);
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql2);

            for (int i = 0; i < 2680; i++) {
                year = yearc.nextInt(2014 - 1900) + 1900;
                num_rating = num_ratingsc.nextInt(1000);
                num_ratingSum += num_rating;
                num_ratingAvg = num_ratingSum / (i + 1);
                round1 = "\'" + round[roundc.nextInt(4)] + "\'";
                sql3 = "INSERT INTO cup_matches (MID, ROUND, YEAR, NUM_RATINGS, RATING) "
                        + "VALUES ("
                        + i
                        + ", "
                        + round1
                        + ", "
                        + year
                        + ", "
                        + num_rating + ", " + num_ratingAvg + ");";
                stmt.executeUpdate(sql3);
                System.out.println(sql3);
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < 58960; j++) {
                idc = j;
                idc = (idc >= 2679) ? 0 : idc;
                year1 = yearc.nextInt(2014 - 1900) + 1900;
                num_rating = num_ratingsc.nextInt(1000);

                if ((belle.nextInt(2 - 1) + 1) == 1 && belec < 118) {
                    name = "\'" + name1[namecounter] + "belle" + "\'";
                    sql4 = "INSERT INTO played_in (MID, NAME, YEAR, POSITION) "
                            + "VALUES (" + idc + ", " + name + ", " + year1
                            + ", " + num_rating + ");";
                    stmt.executeUpdate(sql4);

                    belec++;
                    idc++;
                    System.out.println(idc + "              " + namecounter);
                    namecounter++;
                } else {
                    name = "\'" + name1[namecounter] + "\'";
                    sql4 = "INSERT INTO played_in (MID, NAME, YEAR, POSITION) "
                            + "VALUES (" + idc + ", " + name + ", " + year1
                            + ", " + num_rating + ");";
                    stmt.executeUpdate(sql4);
                    namecounter++;
                    idc++;
                    System.out.println(idc + "              " + namecounter);
                }
                namecounter = (namecounter < 22) ? namecounter : 0;
            }
            // stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            // stmt.executeUpdate();
            // stmt.executeUpdate(sql2);
            stmt.close();
            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Table created successfully");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line makes idc = 0 for each j value above 2679.

```
idc = j;
idc = (idc >= 2679) ? 0 : idc;
```

The first time, it will insert in the table played_in with idc = 0 and will insert that value for each name, when the name counter starts again with 0:

```
namecounter = (namecounter < 22) ? namecounter : 0;
```

It will try to insert the first name with 0 again and it will fail due to duplicate key error

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
            idc = (idc >= 2679) ? 0 : idc;
```

is causing you problems as you later use idc as the value for mid, which is your primary key. This line returns 0 when idc is >= 2679, which will give you duplicate key errors.

Comment: @DaveRiz i can't exeed 2680 as this is the last index in cup_matches so i have to return to 0 again so there is no other option

Comment: Then you need to redesign something because your design is currently causing you that problem.